# EndPoint Routing in NserviceBus

Tags: routes, nservicebus

we have N number of CRM systems that we are planning to integrate using NServiceBus. And we do have N number of services ( developed in WCF, ASMX services) that we need to send messages from NServiceBus and to NServiceBus.

I mean some times, from NServiceBus,  we need to send data to specific WCF/ASMX service based on where the message is coming and type of message.

Some times, WCF/ASMX services(at this point of time we have 5 services but it may grow very soon) will publish the message (those are different message type) to NServiceBus which are needs to be transformed and then send to subscribers.

Is this possible in NServiceBus?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by hosting NServiceBus inside the webservices (IIS). Currently I'm busy with a Asp.net MVC that also host the NServiceBus environment. For communication between services we use NServiceBus while communication to clients is done by SignalR (or WebApi). So technically there is not so much difference between what you want to do and what I'm developing. I already make a prototype that works with several services and several kind of clients (HTML5/WPF/Asp.net MVC).

Answer (score 0):

If you're already planning/considering to use NServiceBus for this solution, I'd recommend having your NSB message handlers invoke your pre-existing web services in-process, rather than remotely.

That will give you the greatest benefits of NServiceBus and minimize the friction that WCF/ASMX might cause.